# Sampling from a Binomial(K, p) with unexpected result

Tags: r, distribution

In the help files for `rbinom`, size argument is a number of trials (incl. a zero) but it doesn't say if this can also be a vector.

The correct way of using this function is

```
table(rbinom(n = 1000, size = 1, prob = 0.2))

  0   1 
809 191
```

But what is happening here?

```
table(rbinom(n = 1000, size = 0:1, prob = 0.2))

  0   1 
894 106
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Argument recycling of the size argument is the prime cause.

Because `n` is 1000, `0:1` is recycled until you get 500 `0`'s and 500 `1`'s (alternating).

All the 0-size ones give `0`:

```
   > rbinom(10,size=0,prob=0.2)  
     [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Resulting in 500 `0`'s + 500 Bernoulli trials with p=0.2, resulting in about 100 `1`'s out of 1000 elements.

[Your results didn't seem surprising to me, but argument recycling can bite if you're not looking for it, and - while there are reasons why the number of successes in 0 Bernoulli trials should be defined as 0 - it may not seem obvious at first either.]

Answer (score 4):

Documentation bug:

> If ‘size’ is not **an** integer, ‘NaN’ is returned. [my emphasis]

You are giving it more than one integer, so the documentation would imply that you would get `NaN`.

Its confusing because it explicitly states where other arguments can be vectors but not `size`. I'd file a documentation bug with the maintainer, which in this case probably means the main R bug tracker.

Comment: Good point.  I was going to suggest that allowing `size=0` was a bug, but it's probably a very useful feature that `size=0` returns zero, so  loops don't crash.  Sort of like the mathematical definition `0^0 = 1`

Comment: I've submitted a bugreport and D. Murdoch replied: "Boilerplate documentation has been added to this page as well as the other
distributions, in R-devel and R-patched."

Comment: size=0 for binomials makes a lot of sense: if you toss 0 coins you are going to get 0 heads. The only conceptual problem is that a binomial with size=0 is no longer random because there is only one possible outcome.